# How to automatically resize input fields inside a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multi-step form that creates dynamic containers for a ship to location. The user has the ability to move and resize the containers but the input fields are hanging outside of the containers when I resize. The reason I need the input fields to stay within the container is because I want to add a shrink/expand button so that when the user has 10 ships on the screen it doesn't become a mess.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/zN62s/5/)

I tried adding the following but it only lets me resize left and right, NOT up and down. I need both.

```js
 $(function () {
     $("#resizable").draggable({
         containment: "#container"
     }).resizable({
         containment: "#container"
     });
 });

 $(function () {
     $("#resizabletwo").draggable({
         containment: "#container"
     }).resizable({
         containment: "#container"
     });
 });
```

```css
 #container {
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
 }
 #container h3 {
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 #resizable {
     background-position: top left;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
 }
 #resizabletwo {
     background-position: top left;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
 }
 #resizable, #container {
     padding: 0.5em;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Ship to one</h3>
    <div id="resizable" class="ui-state-active">
        <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Dept. 1</h3>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment">Address is filled autometically with pevious address</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add to your css : textarea{width:100%;}

Comment: In addition to that also set `box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this some more, I came up with a more heavy-handed, but functional jQuery approach that includes changing height.

First I added a max-width to the CSS:

```
textarea { max-width: 95%; }
```

That controls the #comment width well enough, but height was harder to nail down. I ended up calculating the height of the container #resizable div and then subtracting the other child elements heights, and the padding, to get a suitable number for height. Then I updated the values on resize.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).draggable({containment: "#container"}).resizable({
    containment: "#container"
  });

  // #resizable height
  var resizableHeight = $( "#resizable" ).outerHeight(true);

  // child elements and padding 
  var resizableH3 = $( "#resizable h3" ).outerHeight(true);
  var resizablePadding = parseInt($( "#resizable" ).css("padding-bottom")) * 2;
  var uiResizableSHeight = $( ".ui-resizable-s" ).outerHeight(true);

  // adding statics and padding together
  var staticVariables = resizableH3+resizablePadding+uiResizableSHeight;

  // assign starting max-height to #comment
  $("#comment").css("max-height",resizableHeight-staticVariables);

  // detect new #resizable height on resize, change #comment max-height
  $( "#resizable" ).resize(function() {
    resizableHeight = $( "#resizable" ).outerHeight(true);
    $("#comment").css("max-height",resizableHeight-staticVariables);
  });
});
```

You can see your original code with my code and additional comments here: http://jsfiddle.net/zN62s/63/

Comment: Edited once because I added the js, then fixed my https link.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS rule:

```
#resizable textarea { width : 100%; max-width:100%;}
```

Comment: i tried all of the suggestions above but it didnt work. Take a look at what happens: http://tinypic.com/r/1z56v46/8

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
#resizable textarea{width:100%;}
```

or configure a height :

```
#resizable textarea{width:100%;height:75%;}
```

you can also use calc like :

```
textarea{width:100%;height:calc(100% - 39px)};
```